# Hamburg to Copenhagen

Tags: copenhagen, eurail

I am a Eurail Global Pass holder. RailEurope.com is currently not allowing me to reserve seats for the train from Hamburg to Copenhagen for July 31. Are there any other options available to me?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion you got when asking almost exactly the same question yesterday?

Comment: Bahn site? Yes. It wasn't exactly the same question. This one is specific to a route. Are you disturbed that I'm asking questions?

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for a bit more time until reservation opens up. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Bahn.de and raileurope.com are selling tickets for Hamburg to Copenhagen, but when I select reservation only, Rail Europe gives me no results and DB Bahn says Reservation Impossible. Do you think this is because reservations are due to open up still? The travel date I am requesting is July 31.